# Variable without initializer in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How to implement variable without initializer ?

I found in Kotlin documentation:

```
val c: Int  // Type required when no initializer is provided
c = 3       // deferred assignment
```

but this does not work.
IDE requires to make a initializer.

Comment: Are you looking for `lateinit var`?

Comment: I just want to assign value to "C" in other class, before assign nothing in "c" variable

Comment: You can't late-initialize a `val`.

Comment: so Kotlin documentation fail ?

Comment: Have you tried using 'by lazy {}' to perform a kind of lateinit on the variable?

     `val c:Int by lazy { ...  }`

Answer (score 7):

If you're declaring a top-level property, you need to initialize it as part of the declaration. If you're declaring a local variable, you can initialize it later:

```
fun foo() {
    val c: Int
    c = 3
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I just want to assign value to "C" in other class

`val` can be used in two ways (counting 2 and 3 together):

1. For local variables, in which case assigning in other class makes no sense at all. The documentation you quote refers to this case.
2. For concrete properties, in which case they can be initialized separately from the declaration, but only in an [`init` block](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors) of the class they are declared in.
3. For abstract properties. But in this case you can't *assign* them from other class, but only implement these properties.

Answer (score -2):

For `val` you need to do the declaration and the assignment together.

For your case, this variable needs to be modified after the declaration section, therefore `var c: Int` will be better.

Comment: "For val you need to do the declaration and the assignment together." - no you don't, please see my answer.